# Is the chrome.extension API available on mobile Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a webpage that's supposed to encourage my users to install my Chrome extension if they haven't already. I have access to the `chrome` object when the JavaScript runs in Chrome, but not in other browsers like Safari or Internet Explorer. That's all well and good, but I was wondering whether the `chrome` object exists in mobile Chrome (Chrome for Android or iOS) and whether there is a separate API for those browsers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, extensions or the .extension apis are currently not supported on mobile chrome.